# Calls to update a user return 200 OK but do not update user

Tags: perl, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Back story:

Migrating from the Provisioning API to the Admin SDK Directory API. Using Perl.
I can successfully obtain a Bearer token, and I can use the token to obtain an individual User Resource and User Resource listing of the entire domain. This all works fine. I have ensured that I'm using the proper scope in the token request (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user).

Problem:
Calls to update a user are returning 200 OK (expected) but the changes are not being picked up.

Using LWP to PUT the update request. Here's a dump of the LWP object after the request comes back. You can see that I'm getting a 200 OK response and a User Resource object as part of the response. You can also see that the returned User Resource does not reflect the changes I've sent in the request. I have confirmed in the admin console for the domain that the changes were not picked up.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
'_content' => '{
 "kind": "admin#directory#user",
 "id": "somenumber",
 "etag": "\\"etag\\"",
 "primaryEmail": "user@googletestdomain",
 "name": {
  "givenName": "user",
  "familyName": "name",
  "fullName": "user name"
 },
 "isAdmin": false,
 "isDelegatedAdmin": false,
 "lastLoginTime": "2014-10-02T17:20:02.000Z",
 "creationTime": "2010-01-04T22:27:44.000Z",
 "agreedToTerms": true,
 "suspended": false,
 "changePasswordAtNextLogin": false,
 "ipWhitelisted": false,
 "emails": [
  {
   "address": "user@googletestdomain",
   "primary": true
  },
 ],
 "customerId": "C01id",
 "orgUnitPath": "/",
 "isMailboxSetup": true,
 "includeInGlobalAddressList": true
}
'
'_headers' => HTTP::Headers=HASH(0x2031048)
   '::std_case' => HASH(0x2031240)
      'alternate-protocol' => 'Alternate-Protocol'
      'client-date' => 'Client-Date'
      'client-peer' => 'Client-Peer'
      'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num'
      'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer'
      'client-ssl-cert-subject' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Subject'
      'client-ssl-cipher' => 'Client-SSL-Cipher'
      'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'Client-SSL-Socket-Class'
      'x-content-type-options' => 'X-Content-Type-Options'
      'x-frame-options' => 'X-Frame-Options'
      'x-xss-protection' => 'X-XSS-Protection'
   'alternate-protocol' => '443:quic,p=0.01'
   'cache-control' => 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate'
   'client-date' => 'Mon, 27 Oct 2014 17:48:14 GMT'
   'client-peer' => '173.194.79.95:443'
   'client-response-num' => 1
   'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2'
   'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.googleapis.com'
   'client-ssl-cipher' => 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'
   'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
   'connection' => 'close'
   'content-type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
   'date' => 'Mon, 27 Oct 2014 17:48:14 GMT'
   'etag' => '"etag"'
   'expires' => 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'
   'pragma' => 'no-cache'
   'server' => 'GSE'
   'vary' => ARRAY(0x20311b0)
      0  'Origin'
      1  'Referer'
      2  'X-Origin'
   'x-content-type-options' => 'nosniff'
   'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN'
   'x-xss-protection' => '1; mode=block'
'_msg' => 'OK'
'_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1'
'_rc' => 200
'_request' => HTTP::Request=HASH(0x1f5dc90)
   '_content' => '{"name":{"givenName":"BBB","familyName":"BBB"}}'
   '_headers' => HTTP::Headers=HASH(0x224fa08)
      '::std_case' => HASH(0x1f28c90)
         'if-ssl-cert-subject' => 'If-SSL-Cert-Subject'
      'authorization' => 'Bearer mytokenhere'
      'content-length' => 47
      'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.05'
   '_method' => 'PUT'
   '_uri' => URI::https=SCALAR(0x1cbc8b8)
      -> 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/user@googletestdomain'
   '_uri_canonical' => URI::https=SCALAR(0x1cbc8b8)
      -> REUSED_ADDRESS
```

Here's a sample of the code used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use JSON;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $auth_token = 'myauthtoken';

my $changes = {
  'name'  =>  {
    'givenName'  =>  'BBB',
  },
};  

my $json = new JSON;
my $ur = $json->encode($changes,{utf8 => 1});

my $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/user@googletestdomain';
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 30);
my $res = $ua->put($url,
  'Authorization'  =>  'Bearer '.$auth_token,
  'Content'  =>  $ur,
);
```

Comment: I don't see `Content-Type: application/json` in your request headers...perhaps try setting that explicitly. It would also help to see the code you used to generate and send the request, not just a dump of the response.

Comment: Did you try [testing your request](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update#try-it) in the API Explorer before running your script? That would be a good sanity check.

Comment: I did try testing in the API Explorer and the change works fine there.

Comment: And what about my first comment? Did you try setting the `Content-Type` header explicitly? Please edit your question to include the code you used to create and send the request.

Comment: You were right. I added the content-type header and it started working. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `Content-Type` header in the `PUT` request to `application/json` fixed the problem.